# Sanitizing PHP input to ping program

Tags: php, sanitization, sanitize

I would like to interface a php page to the linux command line program ping.

I realize that there are sanitation issues. Is there a builtin library or function that can take care of everything, or will I have to rely on regex parsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean [`escapeshellcmd`](http://www.php.net/escapeshellcmd) and [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to sanitize variable  http://php.net/filter_var ?

good tutorial

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Filtering-Data-with-PHP.html